# Why is the Callable ABC in the collections ABC module?

Tags: python, abc

The Python [`collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html) module contains many handy ABCs for checking various features of objects, but one that doesn't appear to belong is `Callable`. No standard collection is callable, and [`PEP 3119`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/) doesn't provide any reasoning or even mention the Callable ABC, so why is it in this package instead of somewhere else?

Context:
I'm writing a Python->Java compiler for fun, and I just wanted to see if there was any reasoning behind the decision so I could list that reasoning in my code.

Comment: a reasonable question ... however Im not sure its actually related to programing and programming problems. so it might get smooshed

Comment: @JoranBeasley I'll throw in some context then.

Comment: Where should it be instead? A new `functools.abc` module? It would be pretty lonely there, wouldn't it?

Comment: Maybe it's a *clue.* There are no callable collections... yet!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The module originates from PEP-3119 which proposes:

> Specific ABCs for containers and iterators, to be added to the collections module.

But since then, it evolved to be something more. And now a module description does not mention containters and iterators explictly. It says:

> This module provides abstract base classes that can be used to test whether a class provides a particular interface; for example, whether it is hashable or whether it is a mapping.

I believe it is a `collections` submodule just because it was a part of it in the past:

> New in version 3.3: Formerly, this module was part of the collections module.